# Is there any way to exclude a component via the type table syntax?

Tags: structure, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I am trying to declare a global table **gt_sel2** as type table **zqmqnewslist**(which is a structure), however one component of the **zqmqnewslist** which is **PRUEF**(type **ZQMKZPRUEF**), I do not want it in the newly table **gt_sel2**.

Is there any way to declare the table **gt_sel2** as type **zqmqnewslist** without the component **PRUEF**? I know that we can also do it through a select, where we select all the necessary components of the table **zqmqnewslist** excluding **PRUEF**, but is there any short way?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with ABAP syntax.

If you use the old ABAP editor, you may do it in seconds as shown below. Let's assume you want to declare all components of `BAPIRET2` except `LOG_NO` :

Click the "Pattern" button:

[image: Pattern button in SE38]

Type the DDIC structure, table or view name:

[image: generate DATA for filtered components of structure BAPIRET2]

Select all components:

[image: select all structure components]

Exclude by pressing at the same time the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and selecting the line of the component with the mouse:

[image: exclude component LOG_NO]

Obtained code:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF ts_bapiret2,
        type       TYPE bapiret2-type,
        id         TYPE bapiret2-id,
        number     TYPE bapiret2-number,
        message    TYPE bapiret2-message,
        log_msg_no TYPE bapiret2-log_msg_no,
        message_v1 TYPE bapiret2-message_v1,
        message_v2 TYPE bapiret2-message_v2,
        message_v3 TYPE bapiret2-message_v3,
        message_v4 TYPE bapiret2-message_v4,
        parameter  TYPE bapiret2-parameter,
        row        TYPE bapiret2-row,
        field      TYPE bapiret2-field,
        system     TYPE bapiret2-system,
      END OF ts_bapiret2.
```

Now declare your internal table:

```
DATA bapiret2_tab LIKE TABLE OF ts_bapiret2.
```

Comment: however, this will not solve the problem of maintainability. When someone changes the original `zqmqnewslist` structure you have to change your code to reflect this, and this is what OP didn't wanted, as I got it